# Needs refresh in order to display created items

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am working on a simple tool that adds budgets to teams. It works similar to a to do list.

The delete function works without reloading but the create function needs a refresh (the data gets added to database fine).

This is the create.js.erb

```
$('.budget_items').append("<%= j render partial: 'budget', locals: {budget: @budget} %>");
```

This is the partial: _budget.html.erb

```
<li id="<%= budget.id %>">
<%= budget.budget_item %>
<%= budget.quantity %>
<%= budget.cost_per_item %>
Total cost: <%= budget.quantity * budget.cost_per_item %>
<%= link_to "delete budget item", project_team_budget_path(@project, @team,    
budget), method: 'delete', remote: true %>
</li>

<h1>My Estimated Budget</h1>
<h3>Total Budget: </h3>

<%= simple_form_for [@project, @team, @budget], remote: true do |f| %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.input :budget_item %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.input :quantity %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.input :cost_per_item %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <%= f.submit "Add budget item" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<ul class="budget_items">
  <%= render @budgets %>
</ul>
```

This is the budget controller:

```
class BudgetsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @budgets = Budget.all
  end

  def create
    @team = Team.find(params[:team_id])
    @budget = @team.budgets.create(budget_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to project_team_budgets_path }
      format.js { }
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @team = Team.find(params[:team_id])
    @budget = @team.budgets.find(params[:id])
    @budget.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to project_team_budgets_path }
      format.js { }
    end
  end

  private

  def budget_params
    params.require(:budget).permit(:title, :budget_item, :quantity, :cost_per_item)
  end
end
```

Comment: Is your file name is `create.erb.js` not `create.js.erb`?

Comment: Thanks Pavan, that was wrong in the question, in the library its create.js.erb

Answer (score 0):

We ended up adding a set_project method into the budgets_controller.

```
def set_project
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
end
```

And set a before_action for it. The issue I think we were having was it was looking for a project_id but we weren't passing it a project when creating a new budget item.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe will help if you include remote on your .html.erb. Maybe will be a little harder, but the long-term return is better.

There's a basic tutorial here http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html.

best!